# jQuery sortable onDrop event freezes the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, nested-sortable

I'm using [jQuery Sortable](https://johnny.github.io/jquery-sortable/) library to create rearrangeable nested `<ol>` elements (do not confuse with [jQuery UI sortable](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/)), when i try to execute code (`console.log`) in the `onDrop` event, the page freezes, and the dragged `<li>` element become transparent and floats on the page over the others elements (similar to `position: absolute` and `opacity: 0.5`)

**Working example:** https://johnny.github.io/jquery-sortable/#features

**My code:** http://jsfiddle.net/xdjn2wqp/2/

Comment: Your code should be posted in the question itself as links can rot, and users shouldn't have to visit a third party site to view your code.

Comment: I think it's a good practice when the code itself is too long to be posted on the question, and a lot of high-rep users use reliable third party code sharing services like codepen and jsfiddle

Comment: The only code that mattered was the javascript, the CSS, and HTML were secondary and aren't really that large anyway. Also SO has their own code demo service called stacksnippets (just hit the code button in the editor). Codepen and other sites are only really needed anymore when your code can't be demoed through stacksnippets.

Comment: I still with the third party tools, they offer better code editing tools, like syntax hightlighting, auto completion, live preview and a bunch of things that stacksnippets don't have

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wasn't getting a page freeze when testing your code, but the element that was dragged never got the .dragged class removed from it after dropping. Maybe you meant it appeared to freeze.

Either way when executing your code you get an error on the console

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'group' of undefined

And looking at the code, the _super method is defined to have up to 4 arguments, but looks like it requires just 2

> http://johnny.github.io/jquery-sortable/js/jquery-sortable-min.js
>
> ```
> onDrop: function(a, b, c, e) {
>   a.removeClass(b.group.options.draggedClass).removeAttr("style");
>   d("body").removeClass(b.group.options.bodyClass)
> },
> ```

Non-minified version

> http://johnny.github.io/jquery-sortable/js/jquery-sortable.js
>
> ```
> onDrop: function ($item, container, _super, event) {
>    $item.removeClass(container.group.options.draggedClass).removeAttr("style")
>    $("body").removeClass(container.group.options.bodyClass)
> },
> ```

You however only pass 1, item. And from the documentation page all the examples that use `_super()` use two arguments, the item and then the container

```
_super(item,container)
```

So once you pass in `container` as well, the problem not longer exists

```js
$(".placeholder-children").droppable({
  drop: function(event, ui) {
    alert('dropped');
  }
});
$(function() {

  $("ol.tree").sortable({
    group: 'serialization',
    onDrop: function(item, container, _super) {
      alert("a");
      container.el.removeClass("active")
      _super(item, container)
    }
  });
})
```

```css
body.dragging,
body.dragging * {
  cursor: move !important;
}

.dragged {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.5;
  z-index: 2000;
}

ol.tree {
  background-color: #FFF;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

ol {
  list-style-type: none;
  list-style: none;
}

ol li {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #eeeeee;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  color: #0088cc;
  display: block;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  line-height: 18px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://johnny.github.io/jquery-sortable/js/jquery-sortable-min.js"></script>
<ol class="tree serialization">
  <li class="placeholder-children">First
    <ol></ol>
  </li>
  <li class="placeholder-children">Second
    <ol></ol>
  </li>
  <li class="placeholder-children">Third
    <ol>
      <li class="placeholder-children">First</li>
      <li class="placeholder-children">Second</li>
      <li class="placeholder-children">Third
        <ol>
          <li class="placeholder-children">First</li>
          <li class="placeholder-children">Second</li>
        </ol>
        <ol>
          <li class="placeholder-children">First</li>
          <li class="placeholder-children">Second</li>
        </ol>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li class="placeholder-children">Fourth</li>
  <li class="placeholder-children">Fifth</li>
  <li class="placeholder-children">Sixth</li>
</ol>
```